# varnish throwing 503 error after separating it into container

Tags: docker, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4, varnish-3

Below are the Varnish container and its log and application container and its log.

before i separate varnish into container the varnish was working fine within application container with the same below setup, but varnish throws 503/500 error after i separate into a container

the below log, i see when i try to update the content on application.
**Varnish container IP    : 172.100.0.10 exposed port 8443,
Application container IP: 172.100.0.2**

[image: varnish 503 error on saving the content]

**Varnish Container Log**

```
/etc/varnish # varnishlog
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Service Unavailable
```

**Application Container Log**

```
[root@application-container www]# tail -f /var/log/httpd/ssl_request_log
[21/Apr/2023:06:26:51 +0200] 172.100.0.1 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 "PUT /application/shared-content/59b2a2390d3b922876493013?_dc=1682051211645 HTTP/1.1" 275
```

**default.vcl**

```
# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

import std;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
  .host = "application-container";
  .port = "8080";
}

backend blogproxy {
  .host = "ip";
  .port = "80";
}

acl abc {
    "application-container";
}

acl abc_loadbalancer {
    "application-container";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Use true client ip from Akamai CDN
    if (req.http.True-Client-IP) {
       set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.True-Client-IP;
    }

    if (req.restarts == 0) {
       if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For && client.ip !~ abc_loadbalancer) {
           set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
       } elseif (client.ip !~ abc_loadbalancer) {
           set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
       }
    }

    if(req.method == "BAN") {
        if (client.ip !~ abc) {
            return(synth(405, "Not allowed"));
        }

        ban("obj.http.x-url == " + req.url);

        return(synth(200, "Ban added"));
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "^nl-s_app" && req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = blogproxy;
        set req.http.host = "blogproxy.s_app.nl";
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Host = "www.s_app.nl";

        return(pass);
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "^www\.s_app\.de" && req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = blogproxy;
        set req.http.host = "blogproxy.s_app.nl";
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Host = "www.s_app.de";

        return(pass);
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "^www\.s_app\.fr" && req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = blogproxy;
        set req.http.host = "blogproxy.s_app.nl";
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Host = "www.s_app.fr";

        return(pass);
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "^www\.s_app\.co\.uk" && req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = blogproxy;
        set req.http.host = "blogproxy.s_app.nl";
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Host = "www.s_app.co.uk";

        return(pass);
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "^nl-application" && req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = blogproxy;
        set req.http.host = "blogproxy.application.nl";
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Host = "www.application.nl";

        return(pass);
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "^de-application" && req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = blogproxy;
        set req.http.host = "blogproxy.application.nl";
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Host = "www.application.de";

        return(pass);
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "^fr-application" && req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = blogproxy;
        set req.http.host = "blogproxy.application.nl";
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Host = "www.application.fr";

        return(pass);
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "^en-application" && req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = blogproxy;
        set req.http.host = "blogproxy.application.nl";
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Host = "www.application.co.uk";

        return(pass);
    }

    if (req.http.url ~ "^/xml.*") {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "^api") {
        return (pipe);
    }

    # Only bypass cache for development
    if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "(private|no-cache|no-store)" || req.http.Pragma == "no-cache") {
        return (pipe);
    }

    if (
        req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
        # Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird.
        return (pass);
    }

    # Never cache POST or HEAD requests
    if (
        req.method == "HEAD" ||
        req.method == "POST" ||
        req.method == "PUT") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set a header announcing Surrogate Capability to the origin
    if (req.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "content\x3D\x22ESI\/1\.0\x22\x3BAkamai") {
        set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "akamai=ESI/1.0";
    } else {
        set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "varnish=ESI/1.0";
    }

    # Skip Varnish for the CMS
    if (req.http.host ~ "^cms-application") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Sync jobs should also not use Varnish
    if (req.url ~ "sync") {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "logout" || req.url ~ "callback" || req.url ~ "account" || req.url ~ "/affiliate/") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Normalize the accept encoding header
    call normalize_accept_encoding;

    # Strip cookies from static assets
    if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(css|js|txt|xml|bmp|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|svg|ico|mp3|mp4|swf|flv|ttf|woff|pdf)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    # Serving ESI
    if (req.esi_level > 0) {
        set req.http.X-Esi = 1;
        set req.http.X-Esi-Parent = req_top.url;
    } else {
        unset req.http.X-Esi;
    }

    # Strip not allowed cookies
    call strip_not_allowed_cookies;

    # Strip out all Google query parameters
    call strip_google_query_params;

    # Strip hash, server doesn't need it.
    if (req.url ~ "\#") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\#.*$", "");
    }

    # if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For ~ "80.95.169.59") {
    # if (client.ip ~ abc) {
        # Enable the feature toggle button via cookie
        # set req.http.Cookie = "abcToggle-abc-feature-toggles=true;" + req.http.Cookie;
    # }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.x-url = bereq.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = bereq.http.host;

    if (beresp.status == 500 || beresp.status == 502 || beresp.status == 503 || beresp.status == 504) {
        return (abandon);
    }

        # Stop Caching 302 or 301 or 303 redirects
    if (beresp.status == 302 || beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 303) {
       set beresp.ttl = 0s;
       set beresp.uncacheable = true;
       return (deliver);
    }

    # Don't cache 404 responses
    if ( beresp.status == 404 ) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # Set cache-control headers for 410
    if (beresp.status == 410) {
        set beresp.ttl = 2d;
    }

    if (bereq.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "content\x3D\x22ESI\/1\.0\x22\x3BAkamai") {
        set beresp.do_esi = false;
        set beresp.http.X-Esi-Processor = bereq.http.Surrogate-Control;
    } elseif (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
        unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
        set beresp.http.X-Esi-Processor = bereq.http.Surrogate-Control;
    }

    unset beresp.http.Vary;

    # Strip cookies from static assets
    if (bereq.url ~ "\.(css|js|txt|xml|bmp|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|svg|ico|mp3|mp4|swf|flv|ttf|woff|pdf)$") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-cookie;
    }

    # Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 5 minutes
    # Zend-Auth (EC session handling) cookie isset, causing no page to be cached anymore.
    # if (beresp.ttl <= 0s || beresp.http.Set-Cookie || beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s || beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 300s;
    }

    # Grace: when several clients are requesting the same page Varnish will send one request to the webserver and
    # serve old cache to the others for x secs
    set beresp.grace = 30s;

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Add a header indicating the response came from Varnish, only for ABC IP addresses
    # if (std.ip(regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "[, ].*$", ""), "0.0.0.0") ~ abc) {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Client-IP = client.ip;
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Server-IP = server.ip;
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Local-IP = local.ip;
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Remote-IP = remote.ip;
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Webserver = "abc-cache-dev";
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache-Control = resp.http.Cache-Control;
        set resp.http.X-Edge-Control = resp.http.Edge-Control;

        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT";
            set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cached-Hits = obj.hits;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cached = "MISS";
        }


        # Add a header indicating the feature toggle status
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-FeatureToggle = req.http.FeatureToggle;
    #} else {
    #    unset resp.http.x-varnish-tags;
    #}

    # strip host and url headers, no need to send it to the client
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;

    return (deliver);
}

# strip host and url headers, no need to send it to the client
sub strip_not_allowed_cookies {
    if (req.http.Cookie) {
        set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(abcToggle-[^;]*)=", "; \1=");
        # set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(redirect_url)=", "; \1=");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

        if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
            unset req.http.Cookie;
        }
    }
}

# Remove the Google Analytics added parameters, useless for our backend
sub strip_google_query_params {
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|_ga|PHPSESSID)=" && req.url !~ "(tradedoubler|index\.html|deeplink|affiliate)" && req.url !~ "^\/[0-9]{6}") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "&(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|_ga|PHPSESSID)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "");
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "\?(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|_ga|PHPSESSID)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?&", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    }
}

# Normalize the accept-encoding header to minimize the number of cache variations
sub normalize_accept_encoding {
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
            # Skip, files are already compressed
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elseif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }
}

sub vcl_hash {
    # Add the feature toggles to the hash
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "abcToggle-") {
        set req.http.FeatureToggle = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "(abcToggle-[^;]*)", "\1");
        hash_data(req.http.FeatureToggle);
    }

    if (req.http.X-Akamai-Staging ~ "ESSL") {
        hash_data(req.http.x-akamai-staging);
    }

    # When the ESI handling is not done by Akamai, create a new cache set, because varnish will process the ESI tags.
    if (req.http.Surrogate-Control !~ "content\x3D\x22ESI\/1\.0\x22\x3BAkamai") {
        hash_data("varnish-handles-ESI");
    }

    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "redirect_url") {
        hash_data("redirect_url");
    }

    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
}
```

Latest findings after a debug ofcode base

```
while (!feof($this->socket)) {
            if (($response = fgets($this->socket, 1024)) === false) {
                $metaData = stream_get_meta_data($this->socket);
                              
                if ($metaData['timed_out']) {
                    throw new RuntimeException('Varnish CLI timed out');
                }
                
                throw new RuntimeException('Unable to read from Varnish CLI');
            }

            if (strlen($response) === 13 && preg_match('/^(\d{3}) (\d+)/', $response, $matches)) {
                $statusCode = (int) $matches[1];
                $responseLength = (int) $matches[2];
                break;
            }
        }
```

fgets($this->socket, 1024) return **values** incase of varnish installed as a service in application container

fgets($this->socket, 1024) return **false** incase of varnish installed as a seperate container

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  dev:
    image: xxxxxxx/dev:centos7
    container_name: dev
    hostname: dev
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR}
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    privileged: true
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.2
    ports:
      - 443:443
     #- 6082:6082
     #- 9001:9001
     #- 5672:5672
     #- 15672:15672
      - 29015:29015
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:127.0.0.1
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10
      - dev-rabbitmq:172.100.0.11

  dev-mysql:
    image: xxxxxxx/mysql-5.6:dev
    container_name: dev-mysql
    hostname: dev-mysql
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_MYSQL}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_MYSQL}
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.3
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE:${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:127.0.0.1
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10
      - dev-rabbitmq:172.100.0.11

  dev-mongo-3:
    image: xxxxxxx/mongo-3.0:dev
    container_name: dev-mongo-3
    hostname: dev-mongo-3
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_MONGO_3}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_MONGO}
    privileged: true
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.4
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      - MYSQL_DATABASE="${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:127.0.0.1
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10
      - dev-rabbitmq:172.100.0.11

  dev-mongo-4:
    image: xxxxxxx/mongo-4.4:dev
    container_name: dev-mongo-4
    hostname: dev-mongo-4
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_MONGO_4}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_MONGO}
    privileged: true
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.5
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      - MYSQL_DATABASE="${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:127.0.0.1
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10
      - dev-rabbitmq:172.100.0.11

  dev-solr-6:
    image: xxxxxxx/solr-6.6:stable
    container_name: dev-solr-6
    hostname: dev-solr-6
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.6
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:127.0.0.1
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10
      - dev-rabbitmq:172.100.0.11

  dev-solr-8:
    image: xxxxxxx/solr-8.6:dev
    container_name: dev-solr-8
    hostname: dev-solr-8
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_SOLR}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_SOLR_8}
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.7
    ports:
      - 8984:8983
    environment:
      - SOLR_HEAP=2g
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:127.0.0.1
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10
      - dev-rabbitmq:172.100.0.11

  dev-rethinkdb:
    image: rethinkdb
    container_name: dev-rethinkdb
    hostname: dev-rethinkdb
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_RETHINKDB}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_RETHINKDB}
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.8
    ports:
      - 28015:28015
      - 8080:8080
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:127.0.0.1
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10
      - dev-rabbitmq:172.100.0.11
      
  dev-memcached:
    image: memcached
    container_name: dev-memcached
    hostname: dev-memcached
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.9
    ports:
      - 11211:11211
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:127.0.0.1
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10
      - dev-rabbitmq:172.100.0.11

  dev-varnish:
    image: varnish:7.3.0-alpine
    container_name: dev-varnish
    hostname: dev-varnish
    user: '0'
    volumes:
      - "./default.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl:ro"
      - "./secret:/etc/varnish/secret"
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/varnish/varnishd:exec
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.10
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-varnish:127.0.0.1
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-rabbitmq:172.100.0.11

  dev-rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.27-management-alpine
    container_name: dev-rabbitmq
    environment:
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST}
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_RMQ}/data:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_RMQ}
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_RMQ}/log:/var/log/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.11
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10
      - dev-rabbitmq:127.0.0.1

networks:
  dev-online:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.100.0.0/24
```

**Same 503/500 error after adding below configuration**

application configuration in dev container

```
'endpoint' => [
                    'host' => '172.100.0.10',
                    'port' => '6082',
                    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                ]
```

added below command to varnish container in docker-compose.yml

```
command: ["-T",":6082","-S","/etc/varnish/secret"]
```

The dev-varnish container belo

```
 /etc/varnish # ps aux
    PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
        1 varnish   0:00 varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a http=:80,HTTP -a proxy=:8443,PROXY -p feature=+http2 -s malloc,100M -T :6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret
       18 varnish   0:01 {cache-main} varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a http=:80,HTTP -a proxy=:8443,PROXY -p feature=+http2 -s malloc,100M -T :6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret
```

---

```
docker top dev-varnish
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
systemd+            17596               17547               0                   07:57               ?                   00:00:04            varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a http=:80,HTTP -a proxy=:8443,PROXY -p feature=+http2 -s malloc,100M -T :6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret
systemd+            17928               17596               0                   07:57               ?                   00:00:28            varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a http=:80,HTTP -a proxy=:8443,PROXY -p feature=+http2 -s malloc,100M -T :6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret
```

---

```
/etc/varnish # varnishadm -T 172.100.0.10:6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret
200        
-----------------------------
Varnish Cache CLI 1.0
-----------------------------
Linux,5.15.0-71-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-sdefault,-hcritbit
varnish-7.2.1 revision 399fa7ed46d68f4c4f42a8fd2748339750d99a8b

Type 'help' for command list.
Type 'quit' to close CLI session.

varnish>
```

---

```
[root@dev www]# telnet 172.100.0.10 6082
Trying 172.100.0.10...
Connected to 172.100.0.10.
Escape character is '^]'.
107 59      
tbdxujqstyqxpnpjwhlbmhdjmiudnuib

Authentication required.

xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
101 44      
Unknown request.
Type 'help' for more info.
```

**working configuration, when varnish runs inside dev container**

```
997                 114389              112718              0                   20:07               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/varnishd -a 127.0.0.1:80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -t 120 -p thread_pool_min=10 -p thread_pool_max=500 -p thread_pool_timeout=120 -p feature=+esi_disable_xml_check -p pipe_timeout=600 -p timeout_idle=301 -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256M -n xxxx-cache
```

**non-working configuration, when varnish runs as separate container**

```
systemd+            116915              116892              0                   20:18               ?                   00:00:00            varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a http=:80,HTTP -a proxy=:8443,PROXY -p feature=+http2 -s malloc,100M -T :6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum...

did you see that your application is throwing a 500 HTTP error ?

```
-   BerespStatus   500
-   BerespReason   Internal Server Error
```

The application container log is probably not the log that helps in your case.. it refers to an HTTP connection (and you probably don't have HTTPS between varnish and your application)... and the requesting IP (172.100.0.1) is not the varnish container IP (172.100.0.10). you're probably looking into the proxy container log, that appears to be on top of your varnish configuration.

Comment: That is the only application log i see in application container, i don't see any other error log or errors related to 500/503.

Comment: By the way, this 503 error is not thrown when accessing the web pages, but when i try to save the content on webpage using P

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Varnish CLI traffic available from outside the `dev-varnish` container.

You can achieve this by adding the following line to the `dev-varnish` container in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
command: ["-T",":6082","-S","/etc/varnish/secret"]
```

This will open up port `6082` on all network interfaces for CLI traffic. The CLI traffic will be protected through the `/etc/varnish/secret` file which is already mounted in the container.

After having enabled global CLI support in your Docker setup, you can connect to the CLI endpoint from your application with the following parameters:

- Host: `172.100.0.10`
- Port: `6082`

Please ensure that the `secret` file is also mounted in your `dev` container and that your code can handle the authentication challenge that leverages the secret file.

Comment: Hey @Thijs Feryn, i have updated the question with docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thans for the quick reply, I will try your resolution and come back with results

Comment: hi @thijs-feryn, same error 503/500, please check the updates question for configuration changes you have advised

Comment: FYI, while troubleshooting the control still goes to "Unable to read from Varnish CLI"

Comment: @RajsekarReddy Please perform some basic debugging to exclude certain scenarios: have a look at the output of `docker top dev-varnish` and check if the runtime parameters for the CLI were added. Try accessing the container shell and try to run `varnishadm -T 172.100.0.10:6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret`. If that works, try doing a `telnet 172.100.0.10 6082` within your `dev` container. Just try to isolate the issue first.

Comment: CLI parms added to docker top, i can access varnishadm -T 172.100.0.10:6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret from varnish container, but telnet 172.100.0.10 6082 from dev container asking "Authentication required" and i enter the secret but it says "Unknown request", what should i enter when it asks for authentication? sorry for asking basics, i am very new to varnish by the way.

Comment: @RajsekarReddy Please read https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.6/reference/cli_protocol.html to understand how the CLI protocol works and how the `/etc/varnish/secret` file is used in the protocol. You will need to alter the PHP code that connects to the Varnish CLI by introducing authentication.

Comment: thanks for the info. i will check that, mean while i have also given the working configuration when i use varnish installed inside dev container, and non working configuration of dev-varnish container, if seems the varnish container missing some parameters like -n xxx-acsi, is this what missing in command you provided earlier?

Comment: @RajsekarReddy The `-n` parameter is only required if you're running multiple Varnish instances on a single server. You can disregard `-n`.

Comment: I couldn't cast a vote because i need at least 15 reputations, but feedback was registered. Thank you very much for the support